# Variable in prefab's script doesn't change in my own method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process.start

I have a strange problem with my script attached on a prefab object and attached to a button. I tried to search this problem, but without success.

I will explain a very simple example.
I have a prefab *PlayerPrefab* that is created by a script PlayerSpawn through the instruction:

```
Instantiate (playerPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

So, when the game starts, a new instance of PlayerPrefab is created.

Attached to the prefab there is a script with some private variables (for simplicity I write a simple script code):

```cs
public class ShipClass : MonoBehaviour {
    float speed;
    int count;

    void Start () {
        speed = 0;
        count = 0;
        Debug.Log ("Start executed, speed = " + speed);
    }   
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log("speed in Update = " + speed);
    }
    public void Push ()
    {
        speed = 50;
        count++;
        Debug.Log("speed in Push = " + speed);
        Debug.Log("count = " + count);
    }
}
```

Then i created a UI Button, with OnClick event, attaching the prefab object and calling the method *Push()*.

The behavior is very strange:
Once i start the game for the first time, the printed speed from Update() and Push() methods is 0. But when I start to click the button in the UI, the speed in Push() method becomes 50, but Update() still prints 0, as if we had two different variables speed.

The second thing is that pushing the button, the count variable increments. When I stop the game and restart it, count variable doesn't reset in the Start method (even if Start() is executed, seeing the printing log), but starts from the last value in the previous run.
Also, we have the same behavior like the speed variable: in Update(), count remains 0, in Push() counts continues to increment, like we have two different "count" variables.

I know it is due to the prefab object, but I don't know how the variables behave differently in Update() and own created methods.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Snapshoot can help. Please attach it. And about your variables, you need to set your float how a float: speed = 50.0f; speed = 0.0f.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are calling `Push` on the instance of `ShipClass` attached to the prefab. What you want is the `ShipClass` instance attached to the instantiated object.

```
GameObject player = Instantiate(playerPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
ShipClass shipClass = player.GetComponent<ShipClass>();
button.onClick.AddListener(shipClass.Push);
```

Also make sure in the inspector to remove the prefab from the button's OnClick() list.

Comment: Yes, if OP included the attaching part it would be obvious where the problem lies.
In his case he just creates two instances of ShipClass one when instantiating the object, (its component ShipClass will be created as well, which he is accessing through the button) and second when he creates a new ShipClass. Pluto is right, all he needs is to use GetComponent method to get the reference to the ShipClass instance already created when instantiating the prefab.